# Adding a new spreadsheet in an existing workbook raises HttpError "Unknown name requests"

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm done building the Google Sheets `service` with the code snippet shown below and I would like to know how to create a new spreadsheet (aka *tab*) inside an already existing Google Sheet (workbook) with Python.

```
credentials = get_credentials(client_secret_file_path)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
add_tab_request = {"requests": {"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": "New Tab"}}}}
request = service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=<google_sheet_id>, body=add_tab_request)
```

Executing this code gives an HttpError:

> Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.

The full error:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
>       https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets//values:batchUpdate?alt=json
>       returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.">`

I did **a lot** of Google searching, but could not find a solution to this problem. I did not find this in [the Google Sheets API v4 official documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/sheets/v4) either. Why does not my request work?

Comment: Like this https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/sheet?

Comment: @SiHa Thanks, the link provides documentation for performing operations with HTTP methods. I'm looking a way to perform these operations using the Python client.

Comment: But the Python client is merely a wrapper for the HTTP Methods. Following links from the API documentation you have linked to, yields a page for the [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html#batchUpdate) function. You should be able to use this along with the body from my link to do what you require.

Comment: Got it. So when I tried to achieve it with the code updated in description, I got error: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<spreadsheetId>/values:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests": Cannot find field.">`

Comment: Removed the values() function and it worked for me. Thanks a lot @SiHa. It would be great if you could add your comment as an answer so that I could accept it.

Comment: I just gave you a hint, rather than the answer, which is why it was a comment. And as you've now edited the question to actually *include* the 'batchUpdate' call, my answer pointing you to that would look a bit odd. You are free to self-answer though, and mark it as correct. Don't post the answer in the question as you have done.

Comment: I really appreciate that! Thanks once again @SiHa. I've edited the question and posted the updated code as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @SiHa's suggestion, this code worked for me. Hope this helps someone in future.

```
credentials = get_credentials(client_secret_file_path)
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
add_tab_request = {"requests": {"addSheet": {"properties": {"title": "New Tab"}}}}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=<google_sheet_id>, body=add_tab_request)
```

Note that I had to remove the `values()` part from the API call.

Comment: note you need to execute the request, `request.execute()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add sheets in two ways:

- at creation time, using the [sheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) method
- at any time using the [sheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) method

Below you have a snippet demonstrating both and working on my PC (python 3.6)

```
import os
import pickle

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', ]

if not os.path.exists('credentials.dat'):

    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    credentials = flow.run_local_server()

    with open('credentials.dat', 'wb') as credentials_dat:
        pickle.dump(credentials, credentials_dat)
else:
    with open('credentials.dat', 'rb') as credentials_dat:
        credentials = pickle.load(credentials_dat)

if credentials.expired:
    credentials.refresh(Request())

spreadsheet_sdk = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

# we create a new sheet at creation time of the spreadsheet
create_body = {
    'properties': {
        'title': 'Newly created sheet',
        'locale': 'en_US',
    },
    'sheets': [
        {
            'properties': {
                'sheetId': 0,
                'title': "Created at creation time",
                'index': 0,
                'sheetType': 'GRID',
                'gridProperties': {
                    'rowCount': 2,
                    'columnCount': 2,
                },
            },
        }
    ]
}

new_google_spreadsheet = spreadsheet_sdk.spreadsheets().create(body=create_body).execute()

# we add a sheet to an existing spreadsheet
add_sheet_params = {
    'spreadsheetId': new_google_spreadsheet['spreadsheetId'],
    'body': {
        'requests': [
            {
                'addSheet': {
                    'properties': {
                        'sheetId': 1,
                        'title': "Added later",
                        'index': 0,
                        'sheetType': 'GRID',
                        'gridProperties': {
                            'rowCount': 2,
                            'columnCount': 2,
                        },
                        }
                }
            }
        ],
        'includeSpreadsheetInResponse': False
    }
}

new_sheet_add = spreadsheet_sdk.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(**add_sheet_params).execute()


print(new_sheet_add)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked from me. I leveraged Google docs (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#example) & updated for the adding sheet use case

```
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Create new sheet

    requests = []
    # Create a new spreadsheet.
    requests.append({
        'addSheet': {
            'properties': {
                'title': 'Findings',
                'tabColor': {
                    'red': 0.44,
                    'green': 0.99,
                    'blue': 0.50
                }
            }
        }
    })
    # Add additional requests (operations) ...

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }
    response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        body=body).execute()
```